# Vectors in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra

The vectors A,B,C,D, respectively are defined as follows: (2,2,0), (13,5,4), (5,-3,4) and (-6,-6,0). The point P is  such that
|BP| =1/3*|BD|. Find the coordinates of P.

Upon recognising that ABCD forms a parallelogram where AD is parallel to BC and AB is parallel to DC then BD is one of the diagonals of the shape and P lies somewhere on the diagonal BD. Next, I found the vector BD by doing OD-OB and the vector BP by doing OP-OB where P has the coordinates (x,y,z). I got the magnitude of BD as sqrt(498). However, I get an unsolvable equation when trying equate sqrt(498)/3 and the length of BP.

Comment: I think that $A,B,C,D$ are four point in order to have $\vec{BD}=D-B$

Comment: From the information that you posted, point $P$ can be anywhere on a sphere of radius $\sqrt{498}/3$, centered on $B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \small \vec {BD} = (-19, -11, -4)$,

If the question said $ \small P$ is on $ \small BD$, you can easily find coordinates of $\small P$ using coordinates of $ \small B$,

$ \displaystyle \small \vec{OP} = \vec{OB} + \vec {BP} = (13, 5, 4) + \frac{1}{3} (-19, -11, -4)$ and that gives you coordinates of $\small P$.

In this case, as Andrei pointed out, all the question says is $ \small |BP| = \frac{1}{3} |BD|$. If the coordinates of $ \small P$ is $(x, y, z)$,

$\displaystyle \small (x-13)^2+(y-5)^2+(z-4)^2 = \big(\frac{|BD|}{3}\big)^2 = \frac{166}{3}$

So point $ \small P$ could be anywhere on the surface of the sphere of radius $ \ \displaystyle \small \sqrt{\frac{166}{3}}$ with its center at $ \small B(13, 5, 4)$.

Comment: I just want the coordinates of P

Comment: But is the point on $BD$? If so you need to update the question to state that. If yes then coordinates of $P$ is what I mentioned - $(13, 5, 4) + \frac{1}{3} (-19, -11, -4) = (\frac{20}{3}, \frac{4}{3}, \frac{8}{3})$.